# $cmd =~ s@-fp [^ ]+@@; What does it mean in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$cmd =~ s@-fp [^ ]+@@;
```

Is there anyone who let me know what this regex means in Perl?
I couldn't find any regex like above through googling...

Comment: Looks like it’s just replacing `-fp [^ ]+` (literal `-fp`, space, at least one non-space character) by the empty string. `@` is just the regex delimiter, I think.

Comment: You can go to regex101.com and type a pattern into the bar at the top to test it out and see an explanation of each step. This regex is matching all literal characters except for the `[^ ]+`, which matches a non-space character one or more times.

Comment: Xufox is correct, CAustin is partially right

Comment: You can go to www.regular-expression.info to learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

This removes the `-fp` optional parameter and its value from the command.

---

This takes the string stored by variable `$cmd` and replaces a section matching `-fp [^ ]+` with nothing.

This command is employing the fact that Perl subsitution (or other regex modifiers) can have any delimiter character. What is normally written as `s/.../.../` is `s@...@...@` here. That may be the source of confusion.

`=~` is a [binary binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) which takes the left argument as the string to perform the right argument argument on, in this case a substitution.

`-fp [^ ]+`

1. `-fp`  matches literally.
2. `[^ ]+` matches one or more characters which are not space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer helped me.

Comment: @benjamin-w Thanks for the code tag trick :) I will no longer have that issue

Answer (score 0):

Let's get the easy bit out of the way first. The `$cmd =~` simply means "do the substitution on the variable `$cmd`".

Not all of this expression is a regex. It's actually the substitution operator - `s/REGEX/STRING/`. It matches the REGEX and replaces it with the STRING.

Like many similar operators in Perl, the substitution operator allows you to choose the delimiter character that you use. In this case, the programmer has made the slightly bizarre choice to use `@`.

So, we have this:

```
$cmd =~ s/-fp [^ ]+//;
```

And we now know that it means. "Match the variable `$cmd` against the regex `-fp [^ ]+` and replace it with an empty string". Why an empty string? Because the replacement string bit (between the second and third `/`) is an empty string.

All we need to do now is to understand the actual regex - `-fp [^ ]+`. And it's not very complicated.

- `-fp` - the first four characters (up to and including the space) match themselves. So this matches the literal string "-fp ".
- `[^ ]` - this is a "character class". Normally, it means "match any of the characters inside `[...]`". But the `^` at the start inverts that meaning to "match any characters **expect** the ones between `[^...]`. So this is match anything that isn't a space.
- `+` - this is a modifier that means "match one or more of the previous expression".

So, put together, this is "match the string '-fp ' followed by one or more non-space characters.

And, adding in the rest of the expression, we get:

> Look at the string in `$cmd`, if you find the string '-fp -' followed by one or more non-space characters, then replace the matched portion with an empty string.